# How to use HaxeFlixel together with openfl-bitfive

Tags: html, haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

I would like to build a HaxeFlixel project against a HTML5 target, using openfl-bitfive

In the Readme for openfl-bitfive:
https://github.com/YellowAfterlife/openfl-bitfive#usage, it says:

"Navigate to application.xml of your project and add the following
before inclusion of OpenFL library: `<set name="html5-backend" value="openfl-bitfive" />`"

In HaxeFlixel, there is no application.xml, and the closest thing to
it is Project.xml.

So I put in "`<set name="html5-backend" value="openfl-bitfive" />`" as
the first child node of the "`<project>`" element.

I then run the build command, and get the following error output:

```
$ lime build html5

/usr/lib/haxe/lib/openfl-bitfive/2,0,1/openfl/Assets.hx:487:
characters 31-57 : DefaultAssetLibrary should be openfl.AssetLibrary
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/openfl-bitfive/2,0,1/openfl/Assets.hx:487:
characters 31-57 : For function argument 'library'
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/lime/2,0,0-alpha,7/lime/system/System.hx:75:
characters 2-35 : Class<ApplicationMain> has no field config
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/lime/2,0,0-alpha,7/lime/system/System.hx:76:
characters 2-32 : Class<ApplicationMain> has no field config
/usr/lib/haxe/lib/lime/2,0,0-alpha,7/lime/system/System.hx:77:
characters 2-24 : Class<ApplicationMain> has no field create
```

As you can see, the openfl-bitfive library gets invoked, however,
something goes wrong, and I do not understand the error messages.

What is going wrong here?

Anyone out there who has successfully used openfl-bitfive to compile a HaxeFlixel project, please let me know how!

---

Libraries and versions:

```
$ haxelib list
flixel-addons: [1.1.0]
flixel-demos: [1.1.1]
flixel-templates: [1.0.2]
flixel-tools: [1.0.2]
flixel-ui: [1.0.2]
flixel: [3.3.5]
hxcpp: [3.1.39]
lime: [2.0.0-alpha.7]
openfl-bitfive: [2.0.1]
openfl: [2.1.5]
```

Comment: openfl-bitfive was update to last openfl version in the last few days. Try to give it an another chance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set the HTML5 backend actually, it's flixel's default backend already.

However, bitfive is [not yet compatible with the most recent OpenFL / Lime versions](https://github.com/YellowAfterlife/openfl-bitfive/issues/31).

There are two options:

- use OpenFL's default HTML5 backend via `<set name="no-custom-backend" />`
- downgrade to openfl 2.0.1 / lime 1.0.1 / lime-tools 1.5.7

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, openfl-bitfive: [2.0.1] is incompatible with lime: [2.0.0-alpha.7] and openfl: [2.1.5]. You need to switch back to openfl [2.0.1] for compiling with openfl-bitfive: [2.0.1].